# How to find the indices of matching elements of sorted containers?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the indices of one container where the elements match.  Both containers are sorted in ascending order.  Is there an algorithm or combo of algorithms that would place the indices of matching elements of sorted containers into another container?

I've coded an algorithm already, but was wondering if this has been coded before in the stl in some way that I didn't think of?

I would like the algorithm to have a running complexity comparable to the one I suggested, which I belive is O(min(m, n)).

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

template <typename It, typename Index_it>
void get_indices(It selected_it, It selected_it_end, It subitems_it, It subitems_it_end, Index_it indices_it)
{
    auto reference_it = selected_it;
    while (selected_it != selected_it_end && subitems_it != subitems_it_end) {
        if (*selected_it == *subitems_it) {
            *indices_it++ = std::distance(reference_it, selected_it);
            ++selected_it;
            ++subitems_it;
        }
        else if (*selected_it < *subitems_it) {
            ++selected_it;
        }
        else {
            ++subitems_it;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int items[] = { 1, 3, 6, 8, 13, 17 };
    int subitems[] = { 3, 6, 17 };
    int indices[std::size(subitems)] = {0};
    auto selected_it = std::begin(items), it = std::begin(subitems);
    auto indices_it = std::begin(indices);
    get_indices(std::begin(items), std::end(items)
        , std::begin(subitems), std::end(subitems)
        , std::begin(indices));
    for (auto i : indices) {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you find anything like you want [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)? If not, then there's probably no such thing.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I did, but sometimes I don't see that certain combinations of algorithms might produce what I am looking for.

Comment: It will be hard to combine algorithms from the standard library to do such things because these algorithms mostly care about iterators, not indices... What  you want is basically [`set_intersection`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) with indices in the first range instead of value, but you won't find such thing.

Comment: @Holt, would be even useful if it generated a list of iterators that I could generate indices from, but it doesn't look like it does that either.

Comment: Feels like if I could have a transformation attached to the back_inserter, I could generate what I need.

Comment: @Adrian There are possibilities, e.g. you could create a vector containing all indices and then do intersections using it with a custom comparator, but that's not pretty imo, or you could replace the back inserter with a custom iterator that compute indices but you'd have to create such iterator and I am not sure the standard guarantees from which set the value is given, so it may not work at all... IMO the best way is your solution, maybe with some cleaning as proposed in some answers.

Comment: You should write out what your algorithm (in a human language, preferably English on this site) and not rely on people being able to parse your code.

Comment: Hey @JaMiT. Sorry, thought that the title just about covered the algorithm.

Comment: @Adrian Speaking of which, there is some good advice in How to Ask you may want to consider. Your title is rather long to get the attention of a busy colleague. (A more succinct title might be "How to find the indices of matching elements of sorted containers?" Drop the trivial details.) Also, the body of your question fails to repeat the information in the title, much less expand upon it. (No, the title is not part of the body of your question. Copy and paste if you must. Make it easier for others, since you are the only one who truly cares if this particular question gets answered.)

Comment: @Adrian Also, the title gives the goal of the algorithm, not the algorithm itself. Calling that an algorithm would be comparable to calling "sort the elements of an array" an algorithm. Something that cannot distinguish bubble sort from quick sort is too broad to be considered an algorithm.

Comment: Thanks @JaMiT, I've implemented your suggestions.  Unfortunately, sometimes I just can't get the right words and to wait till I do would take too long.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `find_if` to simplify the implementation of the function:

```
template<class SourceIt, class SelectIt, class IndexIt>
void get_indicies(SourceIt begin, SourceIt end, SelectIt sbegin, SelectIt send, IndexIt dest) {
    auto scan = begin; 

    for(; sbegin != send; ++sbegin) {
        auto&& key = *sbegin; 
        scan = std::find_if(scan, end, [&](auto&& obj) { return obj >= key; }); 
        if(scan == end) break;
        for(; scan != end && *scan == key; ++scan) {
            *dest = std::distance(begin, scan); 
            ++dest; 
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't make it that much shorter, but the code looks a little cleaner now. You're scanning until you find something as big as or equal to the key, and then you copy indicies to the destination as long as the source matches key.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I misunderstodd the question. But there is a function in the algorithm library.

`std::set_intersection`

This does, what you want in one function. See:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    // Input values
    std::vector<int> items{ 1,3,6,8,13,17 };
    std::vector<int> subitems{ 3,6,17 };

    // Result
    std::vector<int> result;

    // Do the work. One liner
    std::set_intersection(items.begin(),items.end(), subitems.begin(),subitems.end(),std::back_inserter(result));

    // Debug output: Show result
    std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

If I misunderstood, then please tell me and I will find another solution.

EDIT:

I indeed misunderstood. You wanted the indices. Then maybe like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using Iter = std::vector<int>::iterator;

int main()
{
    // Input values
    std::vector<int> items{ 1,3,6,8,13,17 };
    std::vector<int> subitems{ 3,6,17 };

    // Result
    std::vector<int> indices{};
    Iter it;

    // Do the work.
    std::for_each(subitems.begin(), subitems.end(), [&](int i) {it = find(items.begin(), items.end(), i); if (it != items.end()) indices.push_back(std::distance(items.begin(),it));});

    // Debug output: Show result
    std::copy(indices.begin(), indices.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately a very long "one-liner".

I need to think more . . .

Comment: Yeah, this was mentioned by @Holt, but it doesn't give the indices of the elements, or the iterator of each element.  Maybe if std::back_inserter was able to return the pointers of the elements, I could use that.

Answer (score 0):

By using `std::set_intersection`, defining an `assignment_iterator` class and a `assignment` helper, this is possible:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template <typename Transform>
class assignment_iterator
{
    Transform transform;

public:
    using iterator_category = std::output_iterator_tag;
    using value_type        = void;
    using difference_type   = void;
    using pointer           = void;
    using reference         = void;

    assignment_iterator(Transform transform)
        : transform(transform)
    {}

    // For some reason VC++ is assigning the iterator inside of std::copy().
    // Not needed for other compilers.
    #ifdef _MSC_VER
    assignment_iterator& operator=(assignment_iterator const& copy)
    {
        transform.~Transform();
        new (&transform) Transform(copy.transform);
        return *this;
    }
    #endif

    template <typename T>
    constexpr assignment_iterator& operator=(T& value) {
        transform(value);
        return *this;
    }

    constexpr assignment_iterator& operator* (   ) { return *this; }
    constexpr assignment_iterator& operator++(   ) { return *this; }
    constexpr assignment_iterator& operator++(int) { return *this; }
};

template <typename Transform>
assignment_iterator<Transform> assignment(Transform&& transform)
{
    return { std::forward<Transform>(transform) };
}

int main()
{
    int items[] = { 1, 3, 6, 8, 13, 17 };
    int subitems[] = { 3, 6, 17 };
    std::vector<int> indices;
    std::set_intersection(std::begin(items), std::end(items)
        , std::begin(subitems), std::end(subitems)
        , assignment([&items, &indices](int& item) {
            return indices.push_back(&item - &*std::begin(items));
        })
    );

    std::copy(indices.begin(), indices.end()
        , assignment([&indices](int& index) {
            std::cout << index;
            if (&index != &std::end(indices)[-1])
              std::cout <<  ", ";
        })
    );
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9GJxrv)</kbd>

It's more code, but maybe `assignment` is a more generic means to do other operations, that currently require a specific implementations like `back_inserter` and `ostream_iterator`, and thus be less code in the long run (e.g. like the other use above with `std::copy`)?

This should work properly all the time based on the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection):

> elements will be copied from the first range to the destination range.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes but it will come with `C++20`:

you can use [ranges](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) for this purpose:

first make a `view` with some predicate you like:

```
auto result = items | ranges::view::filter(predicate);
```

then take the `iterator` to the original array from `base`, for example `result.begin().base()` will give you the iterator to the `begin` of `result` in the original array.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <range/v3/view/filter.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/transform.hpp>

int main()
{

   std::vector<int> items = { 1, 3, 6, 8, 13, 17 };
   std::vector<int> subitems = { 3, 6, 17 };
   auto predicate = [&](int& n){
       for(auto& s : subitems)
        if(n == s)
            return true;
        return false; 
        };
   auto result = items | ranges::view::filter(predicate);

   for (auto& n : result)
   {
      std::cout << n << '\n';
   }
   for(auto it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); ++it )
    std::cout << it.base() - items.begin() << ' ';

}
```

see the [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Dc9L2F)

Comment: Your `predicate` uses a loop, which would be better replaced with a `std::find`. But in any case, this results in an O(n*m) algorithm, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Adrian the big O wasn't part of the question. A better predicate would do the job though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use std::find and std::distance to find the index of the match, then put it in the container.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main ()
{
   std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
   std::vector<int> matchIndexes;
   std::vector<int>::iterator match = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);
   int index = std::distance(v.begin(), match);
   matchIndexes.push_back(index);

   return 0;
}
```

To match multiple elements, you can use std::search in similar fashion.

Comment: But that doesn't match against a list of elements.  That only matches against one.

Comment: Though you can, you would have an O(n*m) algorithm.  I'm looking for better than that.  The one I provided is O(min(n, m)).